# Decomposition of a bivector of a Lorentzian manifold

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras, differential-forms, lorentzian-geometry

In the case of the $(1, -1, -1, -1)$ metric, a bivector (or a 2-form) $F$ decomposes uniquely as the sum of two orthogonal simple bivectors if $F^2 \ne 0$.

I have the impression that it is very little known. Am I wrong?

References found:

- *Clifford Numbers and Spinors*, Marcel Riesz, Springer, 1993, p. 206. The corresponding lecture, given in 1959, was edited by E. Folke Bolinder and Pertti Lounesto.
- *On the canonical form of the electromagnetic field*, Luigi Stazi, Annali dell’Università di Ferrara 52: 127–135 (2006), doi:10.1007/s11565-006-0011-8

Strangely, the editor of Riesz's book only considers the euclidean case, completely different and less interesting, in his book

- *Clifford Algebra and Spinors*, 2nd ed, Pertti Lounesto, Cambridge Univ. Press, 2001, p. 87.

Comment: What do you mean by $F^2$? And can you clarify your statement? For example, the two-form $dx\wedge dy$ has Lorentzian inner product with itself non-zero, but it is not the sum of two orthogonal simple bivectors (unless you admit the 0 bivector as simple).

Comment: @WillieWong: I think F^2 means F\wedge F. Hence $dx\wedge dy$ has $F^2=0$. But also what is the question? Is it whether the claim is true (seems so, it's been referenced) or whether it's obscure?